# How to make a div toggle in up direction

Tags: html, css

I am making a mini menu and I have used bootstrap toggle to make it. What I want it that the mini menu should toggle in upward direction rather than downwards. I have posted my code. If this can be achieve with different method please do tell.

```css
.mini-menu
{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.button-carrier
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 85%;
  left: 75%;
}
.button-round {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 22px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  background: #2196F3;
}

.button-round {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-round:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: scale(1, 1) translate(-50%);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(25, 25);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(40, 40);
  }
}

.button-round:focus:not(:active)::after {
  animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-carrier">
    <div class="mini-menu collapse">
      <a href="#" >HOME</a>
      <br />
      <a href="#" >HOME</a>
      <a href="#" >HOME</a>
      <br />
     <a href="#" >HOME</a>
     <a href="#" >HOME</a>
      <br />
     <a href="#" >HOME</a>
    </div>
      <button class="button-round" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".mini-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want something like this.

```css
.mini-menu {
  right: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.mini-menu.collapsing {
  position: absolute;
}

.mini-menu .inner {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.button-carrier {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 75%;
}

.button-round {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 22px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  background: #2196F3;
}

.button-round {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-round:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: scale(1, 1) translate(-50%);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(25, 25);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(40, 40);
  }
}

.button-round:focus:not(:active)::after {
  animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-carrier ">
  <div class="mini-menu collapse">
    <div class="inner">
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
      <br />
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
      <br />
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
      <br />
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="button-round" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".mini-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: THIS IZ EXACTLY WHAT I WANTZ!! :D